# Cloudformation wait on another resource creation within same stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a an AppSync cloudformation and a dashboard and I notice that the ApiId export is finished creation much after.

I create my output like so in a appsync file :

```
    Outputs:
      GraphQlApiIdOutput:
        Description: Main GraphQl Api ID.
        Value:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - GraphQlApi
            - ApiId
        Export:
          Name: GraphQlApiIdOutput
```

In another dashboard file:

```
CloudwatchDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
    DashboardBody:
        {
          'Fn::Sub': ['{
            ...
            ,{ 
                ApiId: 
                  !ImportValue GraphQlApiIdOutput}]
```

However, I get the error: `No export named GraphQlApiIdOutput found. Rollback requested by user.`
The only way I can get around this is by removing the import value first so that the stack creation succeeds and then add in the import value. I notice that there is a waitcondition but none of the resources are external. I also notice that creation policy is only supported for `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup, AWS::EC2::Instance, and AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition`.
Is there a way to wait for resource creation in Cloudformation so that the template does not try to use an output value before it is created in the same stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this in your code:

```
!ImportValue GraphQlApiIdOutput
```

it means that stack from `Template 1` **must be created beforehand**.

So normally what you do is the following:

1. Deploy `Template 1`
2. When this succeeds, then you deploy your `another template file`.

The `DependsOn` is for the resources within same stack, **not across different stacks**. The same goes for `WaitCondition` as you wont be able to reference conditions in `another template file` from `Template 1` before the `Template 1` stack has been successful created.

Comment: I see, I think I also misused the word template. Within my cloudformation stack, there is only one template file, but for some reason it does not wait on the output value.

Comment: @Niru Which output value? What is `Template 1`? I understand you have a yaml file, e..g `template1.yaml` which you deploy, and then you deploy second template file `another-template-file.yaml`? That's how it appears from your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've used the wrong words here. I split up the configuration into separate files and using an utility to join them together into a single template.

Comment: @Niru `ImportValue` must be external to the current stuck. So if you are trying to import a resource created within a same file as `ImportValue` then it will not work.

Comment: I see, I realized I can just do:  ApiId: !GetAtt GraphQlApi.ApiId instead of attempting to ImportValue. I misunderstood what that was used for.

Comment: @Niru Thanks and you are correct. If this is one file, then `!GetAtt` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the [DependsOn Attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html):

> With the `DependsOn` attribute you can specify that the creation of a specific resource follows another. When you add a `DependsOn` attribute to a resource, that resource is created only after the creation of the resource specified in the `DependsOn` attribute.

The attribute points to another resource in the same stack. If Resource A `DependsOn` Resource B, then Resource A will only be created once Resource B has finished creation.

Comment: I wasn't too sure what you meant by "does not try to use an output value before it is created in the same stack", so the above might not be appropriate. Is the problem you are experiencing specifically due to references _between_ stacks?

Comment: No, the problem is in the same stack, as in creation of the AppSync GraphQL ApiId and the dashboard creation is within the same stack. I also tried DependsOn, but that doesn't work either. Earlier I had assumed that cloudformation didn't need DependsOn since it would know to wait on resource creation within the same stack.

Comment: CloudFormation implements an _implied_ `DependsOn` for any resources that refer to each other (eg EC2 instance in a subnet). However, where the resource definitions do not directly refer to each other, a `DependsOn` can be added to force a particular order.